# Can't go to a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am a total noob to web programming (Started just now). I know C, C++ and x86-assenbly (a little bit). I wanna create my own home page for my browser. It's very basic html for the most part but I want a search bar on the top that redirects to duckduckgo with relevant results and that's where the problem arises. The code I'm trying:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="query"/>
    <button id="button" class="button" onclick="openInDuck()">Search</button>
</form>
<script>
    function openInDuck(){
        var x= "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=";
        x += document.getElementById("query").value;
        window.location = x;
    }
</script>
```

And yeah, I forgot, I am using qutebrowser on archlinux if that matters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **_"thats where the problem arises"_** : what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What issue you are facing ? Is not redirecting to your url or url is not getting correctly built ? Can you do console.log(x) before window.location statement and see the url in console of your browser ?

Comment: It just refreshes the page @PrashantZombade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.href` on your redirect. Also you should change the button type to `button` instead of the default;

```js
function openInDuck() {
  var x = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=";
  x += document.getElementById("query").value;
  window.location.href = x;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="query" />
  <button id="button" class="button" onclick="openInDuck()" type="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

*Do note that it wouldn't be ideal to redirect the user if you just need to do a search through a different api.*

Comment: Not working. Don't know why. I found the same solution on the web tens of times

Comment: Can you add `console.log(x)` on `openInDuck` and comment out `window.location.href = x;`? Would be worth seeing what you're getting.

Comment: couldn't get the full log in qutebrowser so I am tryin in firefox (as its same scenario). It says:

Comment: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element.

Comment: I think the error message tells you exactly what you want to add on your html page, try adding: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` within the `<head>` of your html page, also note the additional `type=button` I added on the `button` to prevent it from submitting the page;

Comment: Great!, its working finally. It was the submission and not the encoding. Thanks a lot. Now, I need to work on multi-word queries though.

Comment: No worries, buttons by default are `type=submit` which by definition will try to submit the form it is in. Also if you don't mind marking it as the correct answer that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I already marked it as correct but then removed cuz it was the comment that solved the problem lol. But now you're good to go again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
function openInDuck()    {
    var    x="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=";
    x    +=    document.getElementById("query").value;
    window.open(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but how can I do the same in the current tab?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your form is submitted when clicking the button, like this it works :)

```
<input type="text" id="query" /> 
<button id="button" class="button" onclick="openInDuck()">Search</button>

<script>
    function openInDuck() {
        var x = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=";
        x += document.getElementById("query").value;
        window.location = x;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the fix you have given here?

Comment: I just removed the form tag to avoid the button submitting it

Answer (score 0):

You are close to the solution. In the JS code, you must add `.href` after `window.location` to set the new href (URL) for the current window. In the HTML code, I suggest you use the `onsubmit` attribute to send the form with an `input type="submit"` :

```js
function openInDuck()
{
  var x = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=";
  x += document.getElementById('query').value;
  window.location.href = x;
  return false; // Prevent the form submission
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return openInDuck()">
  <input type="text" id="query">
  <input type="submit" id="button" class="button" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: In your code ? Because the above code snippet is actually working on stackoverflow..

Comment: yeah, it wasn't working though it looks totally relevant and you spotted the real issue first